# 'BUG: scheduling while atomic' with crypto_alloc_hash

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptoapi, crypt

I am trying to use Linux kernel's crypto libraries to calculate an HMAC value, given key and message. The idea is to calculate the HMAC and insert it in a TCP option during an iperf session (this part is not relevant). 
This is the function I wrote to use the crypto libraries, and it takes two keys of 8 bytes (to be combined) and a variable number of bytes composing the message:

```
void crypto_hmac_sha1(u8 *key_1, u8 *key_2, u32 *hash_out, int arg_num, ...)
{
    struct crypto_ashash *shash;
    struct shash_desc *desc = NULL;
    const char hmac_alg[] = "hmac(sha1)";
    u8 key[16];
    int i;
    int ret;
    int length;
    u8 *msg;
    va_list list;

    /* Initialize result placeholder */
    memset(hash_out, 0, sizeof(hash_out));

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        key[i] ^= key_1[i];
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        key[i + 8] ^= key_2[i];

    printk("A1\n");
    shash = crypto_alloc_ahash(hmac_alg, 0, 0);
    printk("A2\n");
    desc = kzalloc(sizeof(*desc) + crypto_shash_descsize(shash), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!desc)
        goto out;

    desc->tfm = shash;
    desc->flags = CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP;

    ret = crypto_shash_setkey(shash, key, 16);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto out;

    crypto_shash_init(desc);

    for (i = 0; i < arg_num; i++) {
        length = va_arg(list, int);
        msg = va_arg(list, u8 *);
        ret = crypto_shash_update(desc, msg, length);
        if (ret < 0)
            goto out;
    }

    ret = crypto_shash_final(desc, hash_out);
out:
    kfree(desc);
}
```

The error is the following (due to the fact that crypto_alloc_ahash tries to acquire a semaphore and it is not allowed in the current context):

```
BUG: scheduling while atomic: iperf/769/0x00000100
CPU: 0 PID: 769 Comm: iperf Not tainted 4.1.0-gdee0521-dirty #143
Received SIGSEGV in SIGSEGV handler, aborting stack trace!
```

Fix suggestions?

Comment: `Fix suggestions?` - Obviously: do not use function, which can sleep, in the context which prohibit sleeping. If sleeping function's result is not needed *immediately* , you may defer its call, using. e,g. `workqueue`. Otherwise ... your design is just impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being familiar with the crypto library: if you have a upper bound for the the number of concurrent executions of `crypto_hmac_sha1`, you might use a pool of preallocated hash algorithms structures. Given that scheduling/sleeping does not seem to be allowed, such a bound shouldn't be to hard to find: the number of hardware threads will do it.

Also, `CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP` seems suspicious if no scheduling is allowed.

Comment: By using "preallocated hash algorithm structures" you mean to move the line "crypto_alloc_ahash(hmac_alg, 0, 0);" elsewhere, outside the current context?

Comment: Yes, you would have to call `crypto_alloc_ahash` before the first call to `crypto_hmac_sha1`.